# Trouble with array outputs and prompting for user-input outputs

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have some trouble regarding my lab assignment:

When my program tries to prompt the user for input, the program outputs two questions on the same line and only takes the input for the second question.

The output of my program:

> Please enter the name of the second employee:Please enter the number of the second employee:1

(They appear on the same line instead of separate lines)

Also the output for an array outputs like this:

```
0.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0
```

instead of like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I'm not quite sure how to fix these two any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

**Employee.java**

```
//import java.util.*;

public class Employee
{
    private String empName;
    private int empNumber;
    private String empAddress;
    private double empSalary;

private double[] empBonus=new double[10];

public Employee(){}

public Employee(String empName_, int empNumber_, String empAddress_, double empSalary_, double[] empBonus_)
{
    this.empName=empName_;
    this.empNumber=empNumber_;
    this.empAddress=empAddress_;
    this.empSalary=empSalary_;

    this.empBonus=empBonus_;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.empName;
}

public int getEmployeeNumber()
{
    return this.empNumber;
}

public String getAddress()
{
    return this.empAddress;
}

public double getSalary()
{
    return this.empSalary;
}

public String changeAddress(String chAddress)
{
    return empAddress=chAddress;
}

public double changeSalary(double chSalary)
{
    return empSalary=chSalary;
}

public String addBonus(double[] empBonus)
{
    String arrayBonus=new String("");

    for(int i=0; i<empBonus.length;i++)
    {
        arrayBonus+=empBonus[i];
    }

    return arrayBonus;
}

public String toString()
{
    return ("\nEmployee's name: "+empName+"\nEmployee's Number: "+empNumber+"\nEmployee's address: "+empAddress+
            "\nEmployee's original salary: "+empSalary+ "\nEmployee's bonuses: "+addBonus(empBonus)+"\n");
}
}
```

**EmployeeTester.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class EmployeeTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in1=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in2=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in3=new Scanner(System.in);

    Employee emp1;
    Employee emp2;

    emp1=read_input("first", in1, in2, in3);
    emp2=read_input("second", in1, in2, in3);

    System.out.println(emp1.toString());
    System.out.println(emp2.toString());

}

public static Employee read_input(String msg, Scanner scan1, Scanner scan2, Scanner scan3)
{
    String name, address;
    int num;
    double salary;
    double[] bonus=new double[10];

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the name of the "+msg+" employee:");
    name=scan1.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of the "+msg+" employee:");
    num=scan2.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the address of the "+msg+" employee:");
    address=scan1.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter the salary of the "+msg+" employee:");
    salary=scan3.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please add a bonus for the "+msg+" employee:");
    bonus[0]=scan3.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Add more bonuses to the "+msg+"employee? (y/n) \nNote: Enter 0.0 if you would like to terminate adding more bonuses: ");

    if(scan1.next().startsWith("y"))
    {
        for(int i=1; i<bonus.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Continue entering a bonus to "+msg+" employee:");
            bonus[i]=scan3.nextDouble();

            if(bonus[i]==0.0 || i==bonus.length)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }   

    return new Employee(name, num, address, salary, bonus);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem just shift your `Scanners` inside your `read_input` method so they start fresh each time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee emp1;
    Employee emp2;

    emp1 = read_input("first");

    emp2 = read_input("second");

    System.out.println(emp1.toString());
    System.out.println(emp2.toString());

}

public static Employee read_input(String msg) {
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
```

For your second problem, in your `addBonus` method where you build the output string you are not adding any spaces or commas. Also it is a lot more efficient if you use a `StringBuilder` for this type of looped concatenation rather than repeatedly creating new string objects.

```
public String addBonus(double[] empBonus)
{
    StringBuilder arrayBonus = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0; i<empBonus.length;i++)
    {
        arrayBonus.append(empBonus[i] + ", ");
    }

    return arrayBonus.toString();
}
```

Comment: QuQ! Thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need 3 different scanners, one will do.

For the printing part, you need `println()` or use `'\n'` for new lines.

E.g.:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the name of the "+msg+" employee:"); 
System.out.print("Please enter the name of the "+msg+" employee:\n");
```

In the first case, you are calling a function (`println()` instead of `print()`) that automatically appends a new-line to the outputes text.  In the second case you are making the new-line part of the string (which you already used in the beginning of the first line printed)

The array output uses `0.0` because the values are floting point values (`double` in your case), which by default prints decimal parts.  To only print the integer part, you will need to cast the value to an integer or use formatting for the double.

Casting:

```
double a = 0.0;
System.out.print("'a' as integer: " + ((int)a));
```

Formatting:

```
System.out.format("Here is a number: %.0f", a);
```

The number between the `.` and `f` specifies how many decimal places to output.

Comment: I tried one scanner before, but it gave me an output of two lines on the same line instead of separately. I searched up on google, and it told me to make a new scanner because there was something to do with nextInt(). It only fixed the program temporarily and then the same output happened again after I added more programming stuff to it >_<

I also thought it was the problem with println or \n, I tried both, but it still outputted the same thing :(

(sorry if I don't make much sense >_<)